"which is about to run away with this thing"

But this could go another way. The Colts could do what they always do against the Patriots, and what they have almost always done this season against everyone: Struggle to score. Start slowly. Finish on the wrong end of the scoreboard. Slide farther down the AFC South standings from Tennessee, which is about to run away with this thing. (source)

I am having trouble understanding this part in bold. The overall style of this piece seems to be American sports writing. I am familiar with most usages of "to run away with" and I have consulted the dictionaries, but I still failed to make sense of this particular phrasing. I'd like to ask what it means in this particular context. Please don't just go to a dictionary site and throw on the table the first specious definition you find that looks plausible but in reality doesn't fit the context. I'd like to know what the agent/subject is that does the running away.
I considered dictionary definitions like this one "to win easily or be assured of victory in" which doesn't seem to me to work as in the quoted line "which" seems to refer to the preceding clause on the whole or to a fact, rather than to the team.

"run away with" meaning to win easily is idiomatic in British English (and I assume from this in American too). The rest of the last sentence reads as very badly written to a BrE native speaker but may be fine in AmE. I'll leave that to an American to answer.

Yes, run away with has the same meaning in American English. And that’s what it means in this passage about American football, and the NFL in particular. It’s saying, “Consider those teams in the division below first-place Tennessee (who, by the way, seem certain to finish the season in first place without any difficulty).”
